# Converting This hour format into hours in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to convert this type of time format into hours
For Example: In google sheet I have time format like - 00:45:00 , I need this to be converted into 0.75 as hours (45/60 = 0.75), Since I'm having this format like this 00:45:00, I'm not able to do that, could you please help me how can I convert this to hours as mentioned example.

More examples : 2:25:00 is 2.416 hours (2+25/60=2.416) I have this logic but let me know how to convert this as hours from 0:00:00 this format

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explain what you tried that didn't work. That will allow us to understand what the actual problem is.  Are these text strings or numbers? If numbers are they times or dates formatted as times?  etc.  Being more clear helps people provide answers to the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

Since in date format one day is equal to 1, try multiplying by 24 and formatting the cell as number:

[image]